# androidthings not displaying hebrew text

Tags: text, hebrew, android-things

Just installed the 0.6.1-devpreview on the Raspberry pi 3 B+ with and external screen. Installed an app of mine which has text in hebrew but instead the characters are replaced with blank squares .

Dialog with hebrew text:
[image: Screenshot of a dialog with hebrew text]

Comment: You might need to add an appropriate font base for your app to your asset folder.

Comment: did you install a Hebrew font on the Raspberry Pi during installation?

Comment: have you tried it as a normal Android app to prove its a _things_ problem, rather than an Android problem?

Comment: The app works great on tablets hebrew is displayed wonderfully. I tried looking for a way to install different languages or locals with no success.

Comment: RLoniello - What do you mean by Hebrew font on the raspberry pi?